# Do Msforms.Checkbox points to both radiobuttons and checkboxes?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a userform in which I have several radiobuttons and checkboxes. I want to capture both of them separately in my worksheet in different cell locations. But my code is incorrectly capturing the radiobutton caption when it is supposed to capture only checkbox responses.

Following is my code:

```
    Dim ctrl As Control
    ReDim arr(4) As String
    Dim arrstr As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If ctrl.Value = True Then
                arr(i) = ctrl.Caption
                i = i + 1
            Else

            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    For i = 1 To 4
        a = i - 1
        If arr(a) = "" Then
            temp = arr(a)
            arr(a) = arr(a + 1)
            arr(a + 1) = temp
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Count = 0

    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(x) <> "" Then
            Count = Count + 1
        Else
            Count = Count + 0
        End If
    Next x

    MsgBox Count

    ReDim Preserve arr(Count - 1)
    arrstr = Join(arr, ",")

    MsgBox arrstr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
```

Comment: Thanks very much.